# Netcat webserver not reliable?

Tags: bash, netcat

If you create a very simple webserver in Bash:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

HTML="<!DOCTYPE html><HTML><BODY>Test</BODY></HTML>"

LENGTH="${#HTML}"
RESPONSE="HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Length: ${LENGTH}\nConnection: close\n\n$HTML\n\n"

while true; do
  echo -en "$RESPONSE" | nc -lp 80
done
```

Then it doesn't work reliable with Chrome. A lot of the times the page will have a timeout with `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`, other times it works fine.

I tried to debug this issue, and it seems what happens is that Chrome fires two requests simultanously (because it also wants to fetch the `favicon.ico` file) and because netcat restarts after each request, it will be too late for the the second request. This problem is documented also here: https://carltonhenderson.github.io/nc-makes-a-bad-web-server/ Even the `-k` option does not seem to help.

Is there any way to fix this? Because the article suggest using nginx instead, but I would like to keep using netcat.

Comment: Correct, a netcat webserver is not expected to be reliable. Better to use something like [`tcpsvd`](http://smarden.org/ipsvd/tcpsvd.8.html) (or at least a netcat with the extra features used by Ted's answer).

Comment: BTW, `echo -en "$anything"` is better written as `printf '%b' "$anything"`. See the excellent answer by Stephane on [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo) over at [unix.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would separate the serving part from the response and start a client program with `--exec` and also keep the connection open with `--keep-open`:

`serv.sh`

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
nc -lp 80 --exec ./resp.sh --keep-open
```

Then move out your response to `resp.sh`:

`resp.sh`

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

HTML="<!DOCTYPE html><HTML><BODY>Test</BODY></HTML>"

LENGTH="${#HTML}"
RESPONSE="HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Length: ${LENGTH}\nConnection: close\n\n$HTML\n\n"

echo -en "$RESPONSE"
```

Note: You can modify the maximum connections with the `--max-conns` option.

Note: I'm using *"Ncat: Version 7.93 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )"*

Comment: Might want to specify which of the several programs published under the netcat name it is that offers the features used in this answer.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Good idea. I added the output from my `nc --version`.

Comment: In the article linked all the testing was done with the keep-open / -k flag, and it did not solve the problem for the author?

Comment: @Maestro, you _strictly_ need netcat to keep continuously running (not restart in a loop, which means there will be times it's _not_ running between the restarts) and invoke a new copy of your script for every incoming connection. None of the pieces of this answer are optional; `-k` alone is not enough -- follow this answer as a whole. (If this means you need to replace the version of netcat you already have with the nmap one, then _do that_).

Comment: @Maestro What Charles says agrees with what I noticed when I tried it myself. I only got it working combined with `-e`/`--exec` (or `-c`/`--sh-exec`).